# jChart2D - Colors for TracePoint2D

Tags: java, java-2d

Given the following code:

```
    chart = new Chart2D();
    trace = new Trace2DSimple(); 
    trace.setTracePainter(new TracePainterVerticalBar(chart));
    chart.addTrace(trace);    
    // default tracepainter color is Black

    TracePoint2D first  = new TracePoint2D(0, 1 );
    TracePoint2D second = new TracePoint2D(1, 10 );
    TracePoint2D third  = new TracePoint2D(2, 20 );

    PointPainterVerticalBar red =  new PointPainterVerticalBar(10,chart); 
    red.setColor(Color.red);

    PointPainterVerticalBar green =  new PointPainterVerticalBar(10,chart); 
    green.setColor(Color.green);

    PointPainterVerticalBar blue =  new PointPainterVerticalBar(10,chart); 
    blue.setColor(Color.blue);


    first.addAdditionalPointPainter(red);
    second.addAdditionalPointPainter(green);
    third.addAdditionalPointPainter(blue);

    trace.addPoint(first);
    trace.addPoint(second);
    trace.addPoint(third);
```

As you can see I am trying to get three different TracePoints with different colors onto the chart but somehow they all remain black. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is perfectly possible just implement you own Trace- and PointPainter.
Within the new TracePainter tell it to use your new PointPainter:

```
public TracePainterBlank(final int barWidth, final Chart2D chart) {
   this.m_pointPainter = new PointPainterBlank(barWidth, chart);
}
```

Then within the PointPainer be explicit about the color which you set with `tracepainter.setColor(Color.whatever)` and apply it to the actual graphics:

```
public void paintPoint(final int absoluteX, final int absoluteY, final int nextX,
  final int nextY, final Graphics g, final ITracePoint2D original) {
  g.setColor(this.getColor());
  g.fillRect(absoluteX - this.m_halfWidth, absoluteY, 2 * this.m_halfWidth, this.m_chart
    .getYChartStart()
    - absoluteY);
}
```

That lets you color each TracePoint separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think with jChart2D you can only set Color for a "trace" and not colors of individual points.

Answer (score 0):

your code is buggy as you set the color only on red three times.

But as it remains black as you write I fear there is a bug (that code was changed recently). So consider posting a bug at sourceforge if it is the case.

HTH, 
Achim

Comment: thanks, i corrected it - but i found a way around this by implementing another TracePainter